# How to configure the pg_hba.conf file so that only the user postgres can access locally?

Tags: postgresql

I have two users:

- postgres
- user

I configured the file pg_hba.conf with this line

```
host all postgres 127.0.0.1/32 md5.
```

But still allows me to login with user locally.
How to configure correctly so that only the postgres user can access locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line that reads

```
local   all   all        trust
```

and replace it with

```
local   all   postgres   trust
```

Don't forget to run `pg_hba reload`.